# Deleted a Mongodb data folder by accident on ext4, how to best recover data?

Tags: mongodb, recovery, data-recovery, ext4, wiredtiger

What's the best/fastest/safest way to recover deleted files from ext4 ?

Specs:

- The disk is 1TB SSHD (hibrid HDD + SSD), also the partition is encrypted with LUKS Encryption (version 1)
- Mongodb is using WiredTiger as a storage engine.

Also if I manage a partial recovery of files, could I do a partial recovery of mongo's collections?

Comment: maybe you could use backup?

Comment: it's the dev database and I only have an old database backup and would lose a lot of work, I know it's ideal to have backup for everything but that's not the case for this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Step 1: File recovery

Fast Recovery of files using [extundelete](http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/):

```
sudo umount /path/to/disk && 
sudo extundelete /path/to/disk --restore-directory /path/to/dir -o /restored/path/
```

- **`/path/to/disk`** represents the disk path, e.g. `/dev/sdd` , `/dev/mapping/label`
- **`/path/to/dir`** represents the path that you want recovered relative to disk mounting point, e.g. if `/dev/ssd` would be mounted at `/mnt/label/` the full path would be `/mnt/label/path/to/dir` and the relative path is `/path/to/dir`

pros of recovery with extundelete:

- it's lightweight
- can work if the disk is mounted or encrypted
- pretty fast, it gave answers if recovery is possible in seconds and it writes the recovered files with over 100 MB/s

cons for data recovery in general

- no guarantee for success
- won't work if new data was written in the deleted sectors (so unmount the disk as soon as possible and make an image of the broken disk before any recovery)

### Step 2 : repair mongodb if missing data

**Backup before this step, `mongod --repair` could delete good data**

Untested, but from my understanding [`mongod --repair`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/recover-data-following-unexpected-shutdown/) should help repair the database if incomplete otherwise you can continue recovery for WiredTiger with :

- [Recovering a WiredTiger collection from a corrupt mongodb installation](http://www.alexbevi.com/blog/2016/02/10/recovering-a-wiredtiger-collection-from-a-corrupt-mongodb-installation/)